# Find customers whose payments were returned nsf

Tags: t-sql, join

In SQL Server, I have a table `CHANNEL` like this:

```
Pay_Date   AcctNo    Pay_Amt    Channel
----------------------------------------
8/1/19     111       100        Phone
8/3/19     222       250        Online
8/5/19     333       75         App
8/7/19     444       85         Phone
```

And I have table `PAYMENTS`:

```
Pay_Date   AcctNo    Pay_Amt    
-------------------------------
8/1/19     111       100
8/2/19     111       -100        
8/3/19     222       250        
8/5/19     333       75 
8/7/19     333       -75
8/7/19     444       85
```

How could I best join these tables so that the end result is table `ACTUALS`:

```
Pay_Date   AcctNo    Pay_Amt    Channel
-----------------------------------------
8/3/19     222       250        Online
8/7/19     444       85         Phone
```

I am trying to remove the returned payments from the table while retaining the payment channel, but the first table records all payments regardless of if they're returned (denoted by '-' in table two).

Platform is SQL Server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you won't display data only `channel in (Online,Phone)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List `CHANNEL` where it does not have `PAYMENTS` with negative `Pay_Amt` ?

You can use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM   CHANNEL c
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
       (
           SELECT *
           FROM   PAYMENTS p
           WHERE  p.AcctNo = c.AcctNo    
           AND    p.Pay_Amt < 0
       )
```